# A corollary on Fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: complex-analysis

Fundamental theorem of algebra says every noncostant polynomial has at least one zero. 
But how to prove "Every polynomial of degree n assumes each complex number excatly n times."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)$ denote a degree-$n$ polynomial, $n\ge1$. The claim is that for any $w\in\Bbb C$, $f(z)=w$ has $n$ roots (counting multiplicity). This is because we're seeking the zeroes of $g(z):=f(z)-w$.

Comment: Here g(z)= f(z)- w . also have n zeros.

Comment: @DillipKumar Yes, exactly.